# Processing request body nodejs

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

So I've been working on this application using nodejs, and i have to scrape multiple HTML tables from multiple websites. I have the responses already resolved from promises. But the body of the response is a string of whole page, it looks like this.

**output.json**

```
[
   [
    "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd",
    "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
   ]
]
```

I deleted some of the content but you get the idea.
My question is how to extract the table from this string. Or maybe i have to change approach ?

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var tabletojson = require('tabletojson');
var app = express();

var baseURL = "https://guildstats.eu/bosses?world=Kenora&monsterName=";
var bosses = ["Ferumbras", "Ghazbaran"];
var bossesURL = []
var globalJson = [];
for (i = 0; i < bosses.length; i++) {
    bossesURL.push(`${baseURL}${bosses[i]}`)
}
function requestAsync(url) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        else {
            return resolve(body);
        }

    });
});
}

app.get("/scrape",(req,res)=>{
    Promise.all(bossesURL.map(requestAsync))
        .then(function(allData) {    
            globalJson.push(allData)
        fs.writeFile('client/src/output.json',JSON.stringify(parsed,null,4))
            console.log(parsed)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error:',err)
        });
})




app.listen('8081');


exports = module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find a Regex library you can apply a regex pattern when scraping or after you get the string back of something like

```
<table>*</table>
```

That should return any string that follows a pattern of `<table> ANYTHING </table>`

Answer (score 0):

I used tabletojson package

> npm install --save tabletojson

```
function requestAsync(url) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        else {
            console.log(url)
            body = tabletojson.convertUrl(url, {
                forceIndexAsNumber: true,
            },
                (tableAsJson)=>{
                    return tableAsJson[3]
                })

            return resolve(body);
        }

    });
});
}
```

And this is the function, work as intended. Output little messy but you can work on it.